# Creating combo-box in LWC component

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I have used a wire function to call function in Apex class, once data is received.I am creating array of object in format of [{label : 'label' , value : 'value' }]

I used multiple approaches mentioned in below code but #1 seems to be not working although on doing console.log. Array created is exactly same as others.

I am failing to understand reason behind it.

```
@track somevar = [] ;
@wire(allAccount)
allAccount ({error, data}) {
    if (error) {
// TODO add error logic 
    } else if (data) {
        let options = [] ; // used for #4 approach
        data.forEach((e)=>{
           this.somevar.push({label: e.Name , value : e.Id}); // #1 this approach doesnt work
            // this.somevar = [... this.somevar,{label: e.Name , value : e.Id}]; // #2 this approach works
            // options.push({label: e.Name , value : e.Id}); // #4 this approach works 
        });
        //this.somevar = options; // assigning temp array as part of #4 approach
        //this.somevar = data.map((e) => ({ label: e.Name, value: e.Id }));  // #3 this approach works 
    }
}
```

Returning data to combo box using getter as below

```
get options() {
    return this.somevar;
}
```

I understand all 4 approaches are different than each other but cant figure out why array generated by #1 doesn't work in combo-box.

With @track annotation when new element is pushed in array it should be reflected.

As per the documentation under the heading (Observe an Array’s Elements) a very similar example is illustrated
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reactivity_fields

Comment: Oddly, I'm unable to replicate the issue. It looks like track works for getters as well. I was pleasantly surprised by this, but unfortunately, it doesn't help you, because from what I wrote, [it appears this should work](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/zfqGr2vUSRm63wyzmgDl/src/app.html?p=stories). I learned something new today. Still, I'd recommend not using the getter, as it adds no value.

Comment: Thanking more, I hypothesize it may be a specific limitation of how wire handlers are implemented. That's the only meaningful difference between what you're doing and what I'm doing in my example code.

Comment: Depending on what you do with your getter, you might encounter the same issue as me. I asked SF a while ago to fix: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdkRiUAJ/make-getter-only-property-reactive-when-used-with-wire

Otherwise, I would highly recommend the #3 approach in the described case.